# Powershell Check newest log file for latest entry containing error

Tags: powershell, logging

I know I am missing something small.  But, I am overlooking something.  I want the script to look in a specific path for the newest log file, and check the last line of the log file, and if it contains a specific error, have it email a notification.  It finds the newest file properly, but doesn't seem to be giving me the output of the last line.  Thoughts on what silly thing I missed?

```
Set-Location -Path "\\COMPUTER\C$\application\logs"

$latest = Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 
$latest.name

$lastentry = Get-Content $latest | Select-object -last 1

if ($lastentry -like "ERROR: Access violation at address*") {
    $strFromAddress = "monitoring@acertaindomain.com"
    $strToAddress = "LotsOfPeople@acertaindomain.com"
    $strMessageSubject = "Your log has errors"
    $strMessageBody = "Bad stuff is happening"
    $strSendingServer = "mail.acertaindomain.com"
    }
```

Comment: Does the end of the log file have a series of empty lines?  `Get-Content $latest | Where-Object { $_.Trim() -ne '' } | Select-Object -Last 1` will get the last non-whitespace line.

Comment: Be careful with any trailing line breaks. Get-Content splits on line breaks, so very often the last entry it returns is an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I'm such an idiot.  I thank you guys for the input.  All those email tags and I completely forgot the actual command to send the bloody email.
  I just brain farted in the worst way.  But also, your added logic helped proof it.  I of course realized I was jacking up something silly when write-output displayed what I was looking for.

Remember kids, it's all great to set variables.  But don't forget to do something with them.  lol